# Cannot use nx file-server with Angular 17 and application builder

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx

I switched my project from Angular 16.x.x to version 17.0.0 and everything works perfect except for my locally used `@nx/web:file-server`.
The problem is super simple.
The new builder produces following folder structure **/dist/apps/[my-app-name]/browser/[en/de/fr]**.

For Angular 16.x.x it was  **/dist/apps/[my-app-name]/[en/de/fr]**.
I am quite certain the new "browser" subfolder is my problem and I just don't know how and where to configure `@nx/web:file-server` to go directly into the browser folder.

To be clear. The build works fine. The server starts. But then I have to navigate to "http://localhost:4200/browser/en/" and all junks (for example "http://localhost:4200/en/chunk-BX252UTG.js") return a 404 error.

My project.json within /apps/[my-app-name]:

```
[...]
"serve-static": {
  "executor": "@nx/web:file-server",
  "options": {
    "buildTarget": "[my-app-name]:build",
  }
},
[...]
```

I just execute `npx nx serve-static [my-app-name]`

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding `"staticFilePath": "dist/apps/[my-app-name]/browser"`:

```
"serve-static": {
  "executor": "@nx/web:file-server",

  "options": {
    "buildTarget": "[my-app-name]:build",
    "staticFilePath": "dist/apps/[my-app-name]/browser"
  }
},
```